# Preventing WPF window from appearing in Alt+Tab switcher

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a very simple WPF project. It contains a main window. The main window contains a button. this button opens another window using ShowDialog().
My problem is that when I press Alt+Tab, I see both windows, even though I expect to see only one. Can you help me fix that issue?

I tried assigning: ShowInTaskbar = false; in the second winodw. But it didn't help

Comment: What exactly is your expectation to see only one window based on? In my opinion this sounds like a terrible idea with regards to user experience, tbh.

Comment: look at [this](https://www.csharp411.com/hide-form-from-alttab/) i think it will help you

Comment: I expcet it to behave **like in Winforms**. In Winforms you get only **one item in Alt+Tab switcher** and when you choose it they appear both one on top the other one.

Comment: When you call `ShowDialog()` are you providing the parent window as argument?

Comment: In **Winforms I could provide parent window**. in my WPF program there **is only one ShowDialog()** method to call with no arguments.

Comment: **styx** I think the **link** you gave me is about **WinForms**

Comment: Sorry, got that messed up as well. In WPF, you need to set the `Owner` property first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: stys, Thank you very much. It seems to be what I was looking for